# Count days depending on the amount the customer has in his purchase wallet in shopping account

Tags: sql, sql-server, gsql

I have three columns in a table, customerId, date and storedvalue (amount in the wallet of a customer)
I need to count the days between a person loads cash in to his account and exhaust it to zero. For example, if a person loads cash on 2024-01-01 and he finishes it on 2024-01-05 then the day count should be 4. If he loads it back again then the count starts again.

| Cistomerid | date | storedvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-01 | 100 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-02 | 55 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-03 | 45 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-04 | 67 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-05 | 0 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-06 | 300 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-07 | 100 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-08 | 150 |
| 1234567 | 2024-01-09 | 0 |

The result needs to be like

| CustomerId | date diff |
| --- | --- |
| 1235567 | 4 |
| 1234567 | 3 |

In the above example the customer added 100rs to the wallet on 2024-01-01 and spent it to zero by 2024-01-04. the date diff between the day money is added and the day money got exhausted should be calculated and it's 4 days in the first instance. If the money is again added to the wallet after its zero that should be calculated as second instance and it's day 1 again and again he spends all the money by 2024-01-09 which will be 3 days. The partition should happen on 0. He can add and spend any number of times but once the account is zero the previous count ends and new count starts.

Thanks in advance!!

I tried the following script but it returns only the data with amount zero

```
WITH ranked_data AS (
  SELECT
    customerID,
    date,
    storedvalue,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY date) AS row_num,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID, storedvalue ORDER BY date) AS value_change_num
  FROM
    your_table_name
)

SELECT
  customerID,
  MIN(date) AS start_date,
  MAX(date) AS end_date,
  DATEDIFF(day, MIN(date), MAX(date)) AS days_between
FROM
  ranked_data
WHERE
  storedvalue = 0
GROUP BY
  customerID,
  storedvalue,
  row_num - value_change_num
ORDER BY
  customerID,
  start_date;
```

Comment: What if they deposit money and spend it all on the same day? What if they do that multiple times on the same day? Do your dates also store time? If not, why not?

Comment: where does `1235567` comes from ? Also why do you tag `gsql`?

Comment: @PeterB yes he can spend on the same day and on the days count it should be 0..yes the date i mentioned is a timestamp but we are using it only for day level. So if he does multiple transactions on a single day all together sum(storedvalue). I will just see if there is money on that day or it's zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is to identify the related sets of rows which is when the `storedValue` turns `0`. Using the `lag()` window function to get the previous row value and `case` expression to check the value is `0`. Performing a cumulative `sum() over ()` gives you the required grouping

```
select Cistomerid, 
       datediff(day, min(date), max(date))
from
(
  select *, grp = sum  (case when prevValue = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
                  over (partition by Cistomerid order by date)
  from
  (
    select *, 
           prevValue = lag  (storedvalue, 1, 0) 
                       over (partition by Cistomerid order by date)
    from   ranked_data
  ) r
) r
group by Cistomerid, grp
```

Comment: Fantastic @squirrel, Sir the query worked as intended with small changes in syntax to work in gsql. Thank you very much for the logic.

Comment: Please do accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use analytic functions and case expressions:

```sql
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl (ID Integer, A_DATE DATE, VAL Decimal);
Insert Into tbl (ID, A_DATE, VAL) VALUES
(1234567, DATE '2024-01-01', 100), (1234567, DATE '2024-01-02', 55),
(1234567, DATE '2024-01-03', 45), (1234567, DATE '2024-01-04', 67),
(1234567, DATE '2024-01-05', 0), (1234567, DATE '2024-01-06', 300),
(1234567, DATE '2024-01-07', 100), (1234567, DATE '2024-01-08', 150),
(1234567, DATE '2024-01-09', 0);
```

```sql
--        S Q L :
SELECT x.ID, 
       Min(x.DATE_START) as DATE_START, 
       x.DATE_END, 
       Max(x.DATE_DIFF) as DATE_DIFF
FROM ( Select t.ID, 
              Min(t.DATE_TO) Over(Partition By t.ID Order By t.A_DATE Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) as DATE_END,
              t.A_DATE as DATE_START,
              Min(t.DATE_TO) Over(Partition By t.ID Order By t.A_DATE Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) - t.A_DATE as DATE_DIFF
       From  ( Select ID, A_DATE, VAL, Case When VAL = 0 Then A_DATE End as DATE_TO
               From tbl 
             ) t
    ) x
GROUP BY x.ID, x.DATE_END
ORDER BY x.ID, x.DATE_END;
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
     ID DATE_START  DATE_END    DATE_DIFF
------- ----------- ----------- ---------
1234567 2024-01-01  2024-01-05          4
1234567 2024-01-06  2024-01-09          3   */
```

NOTE:

- Innermost query sets DATE_TO to rows with value 0.
- Inner query    sets common DATE_END to rows in the same group (before
  and including    DATE_TO) and calculates the DATE_DIFF for every row.
- Outer query    aggregate columns and group them by ID and DATE_END.